# Julia alias in .bashrc not working correctly

Tags: linux, julia, cluster-computing

I am running Julia on my university's cluster, which runs Red Hat Linux. The Julia download's path is

```
/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin
```

When I run

```
/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia
```

Julia runs fine. However, I just want to type

```
julia
```

And have it run. I edited my .bashrc to include

```
alias julia="/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia"
```

Running "julia", I now get the prompt

```
CORRECT>.julia (y|n|e|a)?
```

Running both .julia and julia results in

```
 julia: Command not found.
```

What am I doing wrong? I also get the same issue when I try to set my path in the .bashrc file.

EDIT1: For reference, here's my .bashrc file :

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
       . /etc/bashrc
fi

module load gcc
module load torque

alias julia="/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia"
```

EDIT2: Here is my bash_profile as well, where I have tried adding it to my path. For some reason, I get the same error:

```
 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       . ~/.bashrc
 fi


 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

 export PATH="/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin:$PATH"

 export PATH
```

Ideally, I'd like to just add it to my path rather than make an alias, but for some reason nothing seems to be working.

Comment: if you r path is set correctly, the alias shouldn't be needed; check the value of the $PATH

Comment: @OznOg I'm pretty sure I have the correct path; I went into the /bin/ folder that came with the Julia download. Running pwd(), I get  /gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin. I added it to the path as described in my question, and I still get the same error. The same thing happens when I edit the .bash_profile. Is the path incorrect because I am on the cluster?

Comment: Set your path to the bin directory...not the binary itself

Comment: I've tried export PATH="$PATH:/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin, PATH="$PATH:/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin/, and PATH="$PATH:/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia, but I get the same error either way

Comment: Maybe start a new terminal, or source .bashrc?

Comment: @Roadowl I did try to start a new terminal, but I get the same error. Sourcing the .bashrc returns       "if: Expression Syntax." &
"then: Command not found." Same with the .bash_profile

Comment: are you sure you use bash?

Comment: It turns out the default for my university's cluster wasn't bash. The answer has been resolved, as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534659/cant-source-bash-profile-on-linux-cluster