# Can't source Bash profile on Linux Cluster

Tags: linux, bash, cluster-computing

This is a follow-up to my previous question:

[Julia alias in .bashrc not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533285/julia-alias-in-bashrc-not-working-correctly)

My main issue is that I cannot add Julia to my path on a Linux Cluster. If I go into the bin subfolder of the Julia folder, I can run Julia itself fine. However, I cannot edit the .bash_profile to get it into my path. As opposed to my previous question, I believe my issue has less with building an alias (or something Julia related) and more concerning my .bash_profile itself not updated.

The Julia file itself is located in

```
/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin
```

I configured my .bash_profile as follows:

```
 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc 
 fi


 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin

 export PATH
```

If I run

```
source .bash_profile
```

I get the following issue:

```
 if: Expression Syntax.
 then: Command not found.
```

As such, it seems as if I run echo $PATH, Julia doesn't appear in my path, because it seems as if I can't source the .bash_profile. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: You're using `csh` as your interactive shell, not `bash`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I'm new to Linux. How would the above differ for csh vs. bash?

Comment: csh syntax bears very little resemblance to bash syntax.

Comment: And it doesn't use `.bashrc`, it uses `.cshrc`.

Comment: Why are you using csh in the first place?

Comment: I'm on my university's Linux cluster. I thought I was using Bash, because I was editing the .bashrc with Vim

Comment: just to keep moving forward, just type `bash` at your cmd-line prompt. Hopefully this will launch `bash` and then you can continue experimentation. You should check w your instructor about why the default shell is `csh` (or someone at the IT helpdesk) and can "they please change it to bash". Good luck.

Comment: Apart from that, it doesn't look like you're adding the directory containing the Julia executable: you add `$HOME/.local/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin`, but say that the Julia executable is in `/gsfs0/data/heathjo/Downloads/julia-1.5.3/bin` - unless there is some symlinking magic going on.

Comment: @shellter You are correct; it was just that I had to write bash. By fixing the directory to what Benjamin W. suggested, everything works great now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I'd highly recommend that you bookmark [bash-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) . Read it every week, (skipping the top sections about versions, etc) and when you have trouble search for the sections "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.